# $.animate vs $.fadeIn for Smoothness

Tags: jquery, overlay

I'm creating a jquery lightbox for a website i'm developing, no thank you i don't want any pre-built lightboxes. curious if anyone knows what would be a smoother fade in for the half transparent black overlay(that fades out the website so you can see the white div popup), would animating the opacity be smoother, or would simply using

```
$('.overlay')fadeIn('normal')
```

be a smoother fade in for the black div overlay background.
i'm so tired right now and for some reason i can't get anything to work... not even a simple demo... and i'm just irritated so i figured i'd just ask... :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$.fadeIn()` uses `$.animate()` under the hood, I believe. So picking between either of these options isn't going to give you a "smoother" transition.

```
fadeTo: function(speed,to,callback) {
  return this.filter(":hidden").css('opacity', 0).show().end()
         .animate({opacity: to}, speed, callback);
}
```

Source: http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/src/fx.js line 97

Comment: 90% of these types of questions can by answered just by viewing the jQuery source and searching for the name of the method you have questions about. This is why I keep a link to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js in my bookmarks toolbar.

Comment: @Scottie You have not understood what stackoverflow is about. It's not about finding the answer by reading the source code or a lengthy documentation. It's about searching for questions that somebody else had and finding a quick answer _without_ reading any project's source code.

Comment: @LarsBlumberg I know precisely what Stack Overflow is about, which is exactly why I posted this as a comment to supplement the answer and not as an answer unto itself. Also this was posted FIVE AND A HALF YEARS AGO. I wish I had your amount of free time.

Comment: Gentlemen, gentlemen 